# How to design/write letters of a slogan?

Tags: design-principles

I want to add the slogan "Development is our strength" to a company's name. I'm not sure how to write the first letters. Should they all be in big letters, or just the first and the last or something different? I tried to find some inspiration [http://www.advergize.com/marketing/brands/120-list-of-slogans-from-information-technology-companies/](http://here). There are letters sometimes big at the beginning and the end, sometimes small the the middle and the end and so on. 
How would you write this slogan?

Comment: This is up to you, as the designer. I think this question is too opinion-based to fit well within the scope of our site, but others may disagree.  Since it is a slogan, I would say that keeping it simple might be best.  You don't want to take away from your company's logo.

Comment: The case of letters can be a powerful design tool. There are many variations. You mentioned big letters (majuscules) or small (minuscules) ones. ***Small Caps*** are available in some fonts that split the difference for a third possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supose you are a programer (as you are a Stack Overflow user)

Although it sunds pretty simple this requires a stratgy of comunication. Normally it is done by a designer. Having said that:

In web pages we separate content from style. But the style is part of the comunication.

AS YOU CAN SEE IN THIS EXAMPLE the simple usage of capitals makes the reading diferent than a lower case text.

So the first point is to identify what words are the IMPORTANT ones. Beyond that it is a matter of good taste, design strategy, avialable space, distance from the reader, color, branding, context, which makes thing a little complex.

If the project is not "that" important, one recomendation is that you start with a design you like and test the combination.

https://www.google.com/search?q=typographic+design

That is why a lot of memes look similar and a lot of "Keep Calm" posters are out there. But it is a start.

There is no rule on the usage of Capitals when doing a typographic design (lucky us!)

CAPITALS CAN WORK

or sometimes you need to keep calm

On It's Usage

`All
depends
on the
overall
project`